# How to create an article translation via API?

Tags: apex, api, knowledge

I am having problems to understand how can I create the translated version of an existing article through Apex. I have the KnowledgeArticleId but I don't know what's the method to create lets say a 'french' version of the master article.

I was trying the following:

```
//Create a draft from online version
string draftKbId = KbManagement.PublishingService.editOnlineArticle ('kA7W00000004DX8KAM', false);

List<Documentation__kav> KBAtoPublish = new List<Documentation__kav>([Select Id,KnowledgeArticleId, TopicId__c, Title, UrlName, content__c from Documentation__kav
                  WHERE Id=: draftKbId]);

//Modify Draft values

KBAtoPublish[0].Content__c='le content';
KBAtoPublish[0].Title='french version';
KBAtoPublish[0].UrlName='frenchURL-example';
KBAtoPublish[0].Language='fr';

Update KBAtoPublish[0];
```

I get the message "Language is not writeable"

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so the solution is to use the method to create a new draft translation which then can be modified and set as completed.

```
string DraftTranslation= KbManagement.PublishingService.submitForTranslation(masterArticleId, language, assigneeId, dueDate);
```

Comment: My answer too pointed you in same directions.anyways not a problem.Just like to inform that there is an appexchange product Cloudwords AppExchange .This app auto translates

Comment: I didn't accept your answer because it suggested this wasn't possible via API, then I ended up discovering how to do it. I do appreciate your intention to help anyway. Also thanks for the suggestion on the app :)

Comment: what i meant was that translation is not possible automatically as there is no automation to convert words into other languages .Thanks .May be i have to rethink on how i need to present my answer to make it readable

Answer (score 0):

http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/knowledge_translation_overview.htm

I would suggest you to go through the above link.Its very clear that this is done manually inside the salesforce or through exporting English version and then after receiving the French Version or any other language supported we import it to have the article translated .

There is no automatic button or an API where you can directly translate .

The API are build according to the above link

1)submitForTranslation
2)editPublishedTranslation
3)completeTranslation

The above methods in Publishing service class can be used in order to achieve translation.Note again that it has to be done manually or exporting and then importing translated article .Also note to publish the article once translation is over.